# .htaccess: less-specific for static client but more-specific for API, mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I'd like is a situation like this:

`http://example.com/api/whatever` will point at a PHP API that deals in JSON.

`http://example/whatever` will point at a single, static HTML file that uses front-end routing to decide what to show.

Is this possible? I'm not sure how to get the less-specific rule to point at the single file and still allow the `/api/` thing to work. Here's my .htaccess file at the moment:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* client/index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/
RewriteRule api/.* index.php [QSA]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this in the .htaccess file in root directory:

```php
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !api\.php    [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/api        [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)     api.php/$1         [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !static\.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !api          [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)     static.html/$1     [L,QSA]
```

For permanent redirection, replace `[L,QSA]` with `[R=301,L,QSA]`

This is a general idea on how to accomplish what the OP describes. Can't be more specific with the available information.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you simply use 2 .htaccess files, one on the root with the conditions needed, and one in the /api folder with those specific rules separately ?